# Mixed linear integer optimization - Optimize Profit based on different treatments to all the stores in R

Tags: r, optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have 4 stores (1,2,3,4) and I can apply 3 treatments (A,B,C) to each of the 4 stores.
Each treatment has its own cost and profit.

The matrix is as follows:

```
Store   Treatment   Cost    Profit
1   A   50  100
1   B   100 200
1   C   75  50
2   A   25  25
2   B   150 0
2   C   50  25
3   A   100 300
3   B   125 250
3   C   75  275
4   A   25  25
4   B   50  75
4   C   75  125
```

Using a simple lpp didn't work on this.

How can I maximize the profit having a constraint on maximum cost in R?
Each store can get only 1 treatment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the mathematical model can look like:

[image]

Here `i` are the stores and `j` are the treatments. In R this can be implemented with different tools. Here I am using [OMPR](https://github.com/dirkschumacher/ompr). A complete R script is below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ROI)
library(ROI.plugin.symphony)
library(ompr)
library(ompr.roi)

df<-read.table(text="
Store   Treatment   Cost    Profit
1   A   50  100
1   B   100 200
1   C   75  50
2   A   25  25
2   B   150 0
2   C   50  25
3   A   100 300
3   B   125 250
3   C   75  275
4   A   25  25
4   B   50  75
4   C   75  125
",header=T)
stores<-unique(df$Store)
treatments<-levels(df$Treatment)
num_treatments <- length(treatments)
cost <- as.matrix(spread(subset(df,select=c(Store,Treatment,Cost)),Treatment,Cost)[,-1])
profit <- as.matrix(spread(subset(df,select=c(Store,Treatment,Profit)),Treatment,Profit)[,-1])

max_cost <- 300   

m <- MIPModel() %>%
  add_variable(x[i,j],i=stores,j=1:num_treatments,type="binary") %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(x[i,j],j=1:num_treatments)<=1,i=stores) %>%
  add_constraint(sum_expr(cost[i,j]*x[i,j],i=stores,j=1:num_treatments)<=max_cost) %>%
  set_objective(sum_expr(profit[i,j]*x[i,j],i=stores,j=1:num_treatments),"max") %>%
  solve_model(with_ROI(solver = "symphony"))

cat("Status:",solver_status(m))
cat("Objective:",objective_value(m))

get_solution(m,x[i, j]) %>%
  filter(value > 0) %>%
  mutate(Treatment = treatments[j],Store = i) %>%
  select(Store,Treatment)
```

This should give:

```
Status: optimal
Objective: 650    

  Store Treatment
1     2         A
2     3         A
3     1         B
4     4         C
```

Comment: Hi Erwin, thanks for this, it's really helpful. However, I am getting Error: protect(): protection stack overflow when trying to run on full dataset. Any help around this?

Comment: It depends a little bit where this exactly is happening and how big the data set is. Some thoughts: (1) one can increase the size of the protection stack (2) if the MIP problem becomes very large use some external state-of-the-art, commercial solvers (3) I think there are good opportunities to preprocess the data to keep only interesting candidates (4) implement some heuristic instead of a formal optimization step. Looks to me like a little research project.